# Delete parent Entity when Child is deleted ... Looking for better approach if there is any

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have an address entity:

```
public Address {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Collection<User> Users { get; set; }
  public Collection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Which is use in many entities (User, Book, ...) using a Foreign Key:

```
public User {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 AddressId { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public Book {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 AddressId { get; set; }
  public Int32 UserId { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
  public User User { get; set; }
}
```

When I delete a Book I need to delete its Address ...

When I delete a User I am also deleting its Books (I have Delete Cascade) so I would need to delete both User Address and its Books Addresses.

Deleting the corresponding Addresses when deleting an User or a Book is the inverse of Cascade Delete.

So I created the following query which I run after I delete an User or a Book:

```
    IQueryable<Address> addresses = _context.Addresses
      .Where(x => 
        !(_context.Users.Any(y => y.AddressId == x.Id)) &&
        !(_context.Books.Any(y => y.AddressId == x.Id));

    _context.RemoveRange(addresses);
```

So I am deleting the Addresses which `Id` is not existent in Users or Books table.

It is working and I am applying it to more than 2 tables as Address is used in a few more.

**Questions**

1. Is there a better way to improve my query?
2. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: I have read your question twice and found that what you are wanting to do may be a serious design. Please think again about the design.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Can you clarify. Would you relate Address table in a different way to another tables?

Comment: It seems the whole design is a mess. Better tell your requirement first and show what you have done so far and then ask for what you are really wanting!

Comment: A mess in each way? I pointed what I am looking for: basically each User, Book, Store, ... can have ONE address or NONE associated to it ... When, for example, a Book is deleted its Address should be deleted since there is no Book anymore. When I delete, for example, a User all its Books should also be deleted and for that I have Delete Cascade between User and Book. But by deleting that User and its Books their Addresses will stay on the database. So I need to delete it manually. Bu please, let me know what are you thinking.